# Disable Ansible gather facts from the command line

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

To speed up execution of Ansible playbooks, I occasionally want to disable gathering facts during the setup phase. This can be done in the playbook by adding:

```
gather_facts: False
```

but how can it be controlled in the command line?

I execute my Ansible playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory.yaml
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`ANSIBLE_GATHERING` environment variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_GATHERING):

> ANSIBLE_GATHERING=explicit ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory.yaml

In this way, gathering facts is disabled unless the play has explicitly set `gather_facts: True`.

Comment: Or `ANSIBLE_GATHERING=0 ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory.yaml` to disable gathering facts by ignoring `gather_facts` on the playbook.

Answer (score -5):

add`interpreter_python = /usr/bin/pyton` to your ansible.cfg file

Comment: Irrelevant! This line only define which interpreter will be using on target machine.